# How bad is the road work on I-80 between Iowa and Colorado?

Tags: usa, transportation, road-trips, event-based-effects

I am traveling from northeastern Iowa to Colorado Springs, Colorado.  I came in on I-70 as I was told there was a lot of road work on I-80. However that was quite a bit out of the way and I would like to drive back on I-80 through some places with lots of memories on way home.

I want to know how the road work and delays are currently on I-80.

Comment: This map may be helpful: http://roadnow.com/i80/traffic.php  It shows current traffic conditions.

Comment: When is your planned travel? This is a fairly specific to you question, and good for only a fairly short period of time, which is what we try to avoid, but I have decided against VtC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the conditions of roadworks changes regularly and is often a subjective matter as to how 'bad' it is.  States give advisories which would be better to view.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the season for road work is whenever there's no snow on the ground. So overall you won't really be able to avoid it.

If you use Google Maps directions, it will show you all of the known road construction points along your route.

[image]

Ironically, at the moment there appears to be *more* road work on the I-70/I-35 route that you used to go to Iowa, than on the I-80/I-76 route.

[image]

Note that it's not currently possible to get live traffic data for *all* of these large stretches of rural highway in the middle of nowhere, though earlier I did see an accident listed on I-80 in western Nebraska on Google Maps, so there is *some* data available, and road construction is being taken into account when it makes its estimates.

I can tell you from experience that you should always expect delays in and around Omaha, especially if you travel through there on a weekday, but the rest of the trip should not have any *significant* delays from road work.